# Vimeo video does not start on chrome in iframe. LoadProgress is not called

Tags: javascript, events, video, iframe, vimeo

This is the html code I have

```
<div class="vim-scale-wrapper">
    <div class="vim-wrapper">
        <iframe class="vim" id="vimeo221913211" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/221913211?api=1&amp;autopause=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;badge=0&amp;byline=0&amp;loop=1&amp;player_id=vimeo221913211portrait=0&amp;title=0" style="opacity: 1;" frameborder="0">
        </iframe>
        <div style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

And I load the video with the following code:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    $(iframe).addClass('vim');
    $(iframe).attr('id', 'vimeo'+key);
    $(iframe).attr('src', 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/'+key+'?api=1'+
                                                                '&autopause=0'+
                                                                '&autoplay=1'+
                                                                '&badge=0'+
                                                                '&byline=0'+
                                                                '&loop=1'+
                                                                '&player_id=vimeo'+key+
                                                                'portrait=0'+
                                                                '&title=0');

    $(iframe).attr('frameborder', '0');
    $(iframe).css({ opacity: 0 });
    player_parent.appendChild(iframe);

    vimeoVideos[key].iframe = iframe;
    vimeoVideos[key].vid_loaded = false;
    vimeoVideos[key].vid_buffered = false;
    vimeoVideos[key].autoplay = autoplay;

    var interaction_preventer = document.createElement('div');
    $(interaction_preventer).css({
        position: 'absolute',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
    });
    player_parent.appendChild(interaction_preventer);

    iframe.onload = function() {
        vimeoVideos[key].vid_loaded = true;
        console.log('Vimeo', key, 'iframe loaded');
    };
    window.addEventListener('message', vimeoEvents.bind(null, key), false);
```

Where I bind an event listener which looks like this:

```
function vimeoEvents(key, evt) {
    if (!(/^https?:\/\/player.vimeo.com/).test(evt.origin) || !vimeoVideos[key].iframe.contentWindow) {
        return false;
    }
    var data = (evt.data);
    if(typeof data === 'string') {
        data = JSON.parse(evt.data);
    }
    console.log("vimeoEvents called: " + data.event);
    switch (data.event) {
        case 'ready':
            vimeoVideos[key].iframe.contentWindow.postMessage({method: 'addEventListener', value: 'loadProgress'}, '*');
            break;
        case 'loadProgress':
            if($(vimeoVideos[key].iframe).css('opacity') == 0)
                $(vimeoVideos[key].iframe).css({ opacity: 1 });
            break
        case 'progress':
            if (vimeoVideos[key].vid_loaded && !vimeoVideos[key].vid_buffered && data.data.percent === 1) {
                vimeoVideos[key].vid_buffered = true;
                $(vimeoVideos[key].iframe).css({ opacity: 1 });
                console.log('Vimeo', key, 'buffered');

                if($scope.dynamicItems[$scope.index].vimeoId === key && $scope.cycleDuration > 0) {
                    $scope.activateItem($scope.index);
                } else {
                    // prevent movies from playing out of view
                    vimeoVideos[key].iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify({ method: 'pause' }), '*');
                    // vimeoVideos[key].iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify({ method: 'seekTo', value: 0 }), '*');
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

On Firefox, I get for this line:  `console.log("vimeoEvents called: " + data.event);` Just 1 "ready" event and then a lot of "LoadProgress" which is what I want. but on Chrome I get around 25 ready events, and no "LoadProgress"

Example: https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/39260/829560/k8hCm4vy6KSQE8I/upload.png

## EDIT:

this is the link I create, and tried it in chrome, but still doesn't autoplay, why? when I have autoplay=1 in my code:

```
https://player.vimeo.com/video/163821487?api=1&autopause=0&autoplay=1&badge=0&byline=0&loop=1&player_id=vimeo163821487&portrait=0&title=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the muted=1 attribute, made it work on Chrome. like this:

`$(iframe).attr('src', 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/'+key+'?api=1'+
                                                                    '&autopause=0'+
                                                                    '&autoplay=1'+
                                                                    '&badge=0'+
                                                                    '&byline=0'+
                                                                    '&loop=1'+
                                                                    '&player_id=vimeo'+key+
                                                                    '&portrait=0'+
                                                                    '&muted=1' +
                                                                    '&title=0');`